# TextView extra padding ellipsize middle

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` with next params

```
<item name="android:gravity">end|center_vertical</item>
<item name="android:ellipsize">middle</item>
```

`TextView` adds +/- 36dp padding at start, when text is ellipsized[image: 1]

But when text is not ellisized no extra padding is added.[image: 2]

How can I fix it? I want text fit `TextView`, like on the second screenshot.

UPD1. 
Issue can be reproduced with this snippet of code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you add your layout please

Comment: can you provide your complete text view code

Comment: @ManoharReddy I added a code snippet

Comment: @AbhayTomar I added a code snippet

Comment: Where are you expecting this padding?

Comment: @Boken I don't expecting padding. I don't know why, but `TextView` adds it by itself, when text is ellipsized. I want my text fit the `TextView`.

Comment: Can not reproduce.

Comment: remove the gravity and see if occur again

Comment: @Boken have you tried a code snippet from update?  `TextView` has a great padding at start.

Comment: @AbhayTomar if gravity is removed, text just moved to start, but its size is not adjusted.

Comment: the code is not reproduced try add `android:padding=0dp` and if you need space at the start and the use margins `android:layout_marginStart=36dp` and `android:layout_marginEnd=36dp`

Answer (score -1):

Change android:ellipsize="middle" to android:ellipsize="end".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="36dp"
        android:paddingEnd="36dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and  typesetting industry." />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need ellipsize middle)

Comment: I see, so you need use margins